# how to implement search functionality on tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, search, uitableview

i have a tableview. i loaded the rules into the table of search view controller.
when i type character into searchbar how to implement search functionality and how to add it to the `rulesArray`.
i have an array 'rulesArray" with all rules like below.

```
[rulesArray addObject:[rules objectAtIndex:k]];
```

Rule is a class. Also I want to add rule type to the rulesArray.

How to do both issues?

Code is below:

```
Rule *bRule;
for(bRule in rulesArray)
    {
        NSString *name=(NSString *) bTopic;
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
            {
                [rulesArray addObject:name];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 arrays. One with ALL of your rules and one for the searchbar.

if the searchbar is empty, copy all items of the "full"-array to the "search"-array.

the searchbarArray is connected with the tableView, always! the fullArray exists just for searching in it.

```
-(void)search:(NSString*)searchTerm
{
    [searchArray removeAllObjects];
    Rule *bRule;
    for(bRule in rulesArray)
    {
       //if bRule contains "searchTerm" add it to the searchArray;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```